# I need to get product url on product save after event in magento 2

Tags: product, magento-2.1, event-observer, product-urls

I want to access product url from product collection after product save event in magento 2. i have try to some code but its return url with admin code and key.

i want to clean url no need to key and other paramenter in url.

**event file**

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
echo "<pre>"; print_r($product->getProductUrl());
```

**Get Following output :**

```
admin/catalog/product/view/id/36/s/aim-analog-watch/key/7a1aeddd7ca27d6fc9daf52478db967c889d95d6d74350e6009ed44e06779fa5/
```

**I Need to clean url**

```
http://localhost/magento121new/aim-analog-watch.html
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your code and problem with the code to the question.

Comment: Please see my updated question

Answer (score 1):

Save after is admin event so you can't get direct product url use below code

```
$id=$product->getId();

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

//Load product by product id
$productData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository')->getById($id);

echo $p_url=$product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($productData);
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor::load() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento121new/app/code/DD/Outofstock/Observer/Stockchange.php:27 Stack trace: #0

Comment: Now check update answer use  "getById" instated of load, remove var/generation

Comment: http://localhost/magento121new/admin/catalog/product/view/id/36/s/aim-analog-watch/key/7a1aeddd7ca27d6fc9daf52478db967c889d95d6d74350e6009ed44e06779fa5/

Comment: i need to clean url : http://localhost/magento121new/aim-analog-watch.html.  please read my question proper

Comment: need some customization as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Create **events.xml** at **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml** as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="custom_event" instance="Vendor\Modulename\Model\Observer" />
    </event>   
</config>
```

Create **Observer.php** at **app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Observer.php** as below

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Observer implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $catalogProductHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProductHelper
    ) {
        $this->catalogProductHelper = $catalogProductHelper;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $product = $observer->getProduct();
       return $this->catalogProductHelper->getProductUrl($observer->getProduct()->getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: not as my requirement  :http://localhost/magento121new/admin/catalog/product/view/id/36/s/aim-analog-watch/key/7a1aeddd7ca27d6fc9daf52478db967c889d95d6d74350e6009ed44e06779fa5/

Comment: i want to : http://localhost/magento121new/aim-analog-watch.html clean url

Comment: it is working for me, it's giving clean url as per your requiremnet `http://localhost:8080/magento204/test-seller.html`

Comment: Please check i have add screen shot of url which i have got

Comment: May be you are doing something wrong post your whole code which you have tried. Because it is giving me rewrite product url

Comment: I dont know @prashant, but thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

you can get the Product information after `catalog_product_save_after` Observer

```
<?php

namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Observer\Backend;


class AfterProductSaveObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface{


/**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface
    )
    {

        $this->_storeManager = $storeManagerInterface;
    }

    /**
     * Product after save event handler
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        /** @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $urlKey = $this->_storeManager->getStore(1)->getBaseUrl() . $product->getUrlKey();// it will return the product url

    }

}
```

Comment: I have used this but need product url on this event

Comment: @AjayPatel see my updated answer.

Comment: Its return url key how to concatenate url suffix

Comment: @AjayPatel see my updated answer

Comment: i have ask about suffix not prefix like .html or other